# Sqlite3 strange behaviour

Tags: sqlite, swift3, xcode8-beta6

I cannot import **sqlite3** at all! Even though I created bridging header, imported libraries nothing works in swift. But when I tried in Objective-C, it worked just perfectly!

There is also another issue... The simulator also throws an error on the physical device. The database connection is established, I can retrieve data, but there is no way I can submit data to the datase;

### ERROR:

> No such table 'username'

Hope someone could help me out!

Comment: show some code.plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reconnect the database and try to recreate the bridging header. Maybe it is a connection error or something. As soon as you haven't provided any **code...**

Comment: Thank you, it actually worked fine after I've recreated the database! I messed up the tables in a specific section for the physical device! I will accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

I've reconnected the database and re-imported the module. The issue has been solved by changing the format of the database from `.sqlite` to `.db` in terminal.